# Need chilkat rsa SignHashENC (sha256) alternative

Tags: delphi, rsa, free, sha256, sign

I found the source code that made the correct calculation, but I cannot use it because it is a paid source.I tested the free alternatives but realized that it did not make the correct calculation. I may have done it wrong because I am not very good.

I use it with Chilkat as follows.

```
    var
  pkey: TPrivateKey;
  success: Integer;
  pkeyXml: WideString;
  Rsa: TChilkatRsa;
  strData: WideString;
  hexSig: WideString;

begin

  pkey := TPrivateKey.Create(Self);

  success := pkey.LoadPkcs1File('private.pem');

  pkeyXml := pkey.GetXml();

  Rsa := TChilkatRsa.Create(Self);

  success := Rsa.ImportPrivateKey(pkeyXml);
  if (success <> 1) then
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Rsa.LastErrorText);
    Exit;
  end;

  Rsa.EncodingMode := 'hex';

  Rsa.LittleEndian := 0;

  strData := Memo1.Text;

  hexSig := Rsa.SignHashENC(strData, 'sha256');

  Memo1.Lines.Add(hexSig);

  Memo1.Lines.Add('Success!');
end;
```

the result she sent me (in hex)

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

private.pem

> -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- MIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQCvYJ1Ae1GtrFe8
>   qD1jta6yCZ6FgvWI621uia5ljlTMXYEvcAbOFb95B0EsAs6uFQBMxkWQQ36p+Aov
>   YncEXAvdpj/0WBrNY2+MrasHSlEALAUoKI0ATCg565JH/SncgMYtCcljBs30mjol
>   dg+NyIpkc2uZIwPx8DVB71DTKIt6OzTlabDARvfXU1VyR6hk9uppJ7S3tDHlJ2Sg
>   BDUShh3e7MLF+KzZ4UcYfd1/2LkPw/fWpOj6ndSqczTBqC+0VGwUOWUyRVnMgHLi
>   7H2fzKSNi+SI9QqaOWyvpzQ2T7W+ezN3MI5kosCyaAkLExOvtaU1BcS57ZTz4lHr
>   ucz4tnSvAgMBAAECggEAHLrHB/kruDezZ8Rnyh3JMIFC5rw9XOC0XJdRanGWkqP+
>   tba0Zq5JX5pAouUS1pG6KtmQK8HizhVEFd8bgCtUBktlzrFgMqVHcNRCYD9cZZrQ
>   fXOnJZVUQajFneVrJiQyUs53nzFOK/PX8qsUgTWI9kuyJLQHwWqITvTVWMIblzo2
>   L2hGGJaix37chuU/VK2nMcCe/NOToUHGeWKUA4heJbtmHU60IJSm+z8Rutizk497
>   01qMQOuMlyGNipGlHEtSOnFoZpJyHnYi7M416j8Rmopae0LJ6y+IxigKSZBnt1BL
>   0tYcu/ge5V2d9OrW6cVXLC3QzF/fgIbAgvkKjbPjgQKBgQDh7ZHx1GhIfrSkDlwN
>   6tJP3FUsOBKxk+9gjvgp0EwkhpjeNeYipBYzcTSYOuum3CdbUNqFHmFf7Cin3/gY
>   gcH0Yj2SL35pgw1KQhaNzsuZtQ4JqR6YCDL4Yjzeb6lHalxwjmuSNl5IMM9i9Dop
>   8qL7BUqtMjd/HOgcvsMLbKCBgwKBgQDGuIwS1dHS30HjO2/XqklT+6iMX+dO/GR4
>   KgLzE8Rs/a4H1ihAmAQf3VFax4np2YADFXjBDyx91f1fMRA9x7x4UiKr58/jSykc
>   WXbfl0aT9rplnSMCc6jjMGaCYCXUAqpSqurEDDJHu0n59pcCbWyuWNDpH4pPDull
>   ZZUlWDx0ZQKBgQCNuTCfCcZtC4aXjyZx2Icbb7TCK16WpJ057hWAbVkGZKSKaDc4
>   LcR7ep0qjXN71YiewMaDUP52ZLdQL6/695LKkcHb7Q0YdQwmM/Tf+gRAJJJsvvkh
>   F6uZok5anqMK2I6qULzsGEzmbi/5/Ahsffd9DeG9ac3kYCa+uW+yv+6jrwKBgQCS
>   zPY9W9Obce5cjSX8LgHplrlWqepYgT8/Pdnb9DhhQ63ygBRQU3yIhZh59Xo+VLyq
>   iowgIrN9aj24uqgC27CxOgv+7kq24GlIVhbo6fnriJL+Sez4/LRA0RqJKboIOsfU
>   NgskNNZYA1WM4MuBsZBd46LA9NnZuWxVyYs6gUp3uQKBgEYr7AeIugyrTAWRDylD
>   7mzKpXIbxPd+a1YcjRKmtSIkAYCHg2h8GVOWFjTn73cV1IttQTLrhQX87m23UdNY
>   fQGe4HbWqOlDwbvNRqkslvOfbf3z0PVAUghf9CbUjxDRO15okmuJfnj5WpC73OWx
>   Kgv1OZWRdmV+AZQwku0GTXvl
>   -----END PRIVATE KEY-----

Calculate text.

> 2898D62D0596658FA726E4B78597C384192AB57470B859F875B1872649C9E498

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: I don't know how chilkat works, is it a SHA256 hash you need? I've created alternatives here: http://yoy.be/md5.html

Comment: @MartynA With which other plugins, can I calculate rsa?

Comment: @StijnSanders my goal is to be able to calculate rsa.

Comment: @MesutKaanYÖRÜK: You can't ask for component recommendations here. It's against the site guidelines. Please edit your question and provide more information than *it doesn't provide the correct calculations* also. There needs to be a **clear problem description** and a **specific question** being ask.